# Can you let me know what all needs to be updated in azuree-pipeline.yml file for selenium cucumber framework by using java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, yaml, azure-pipelines, cucumber-java

below is the snap of the yml file: please correct me if I am doing something wrong. I am facing exception while triggering the build using pipeline.
Added our project structure below [image]

```
trigger:
- local

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/cucumber.json'
    testRunTitle: 'Cucumber Tests'
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    pathToPublish: 'test-output' # Update this with the path to your Extent Reports
    artifactName: 'extentreports'
    goals: 'verify'
```

Comment: When you use the current YAML sample, will it show any errors or it can run successfully?   Can you share some details about the Pipeline run result?

Comment: error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project TestAutomation: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 11.0.19_7 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: From the error message, it seems that the project requires java version 11.0.19. How you define the java version in Pom.xml?

Comment: <java.version>11.0.19_7</java.version>

Comment: Can you change the java version to 11?  **<java.version>11</java.version>** In Azure DevOps pipeline, the java version pre-installed version is 11.0.21. Based on my test, it will use the 11.0.21 by default

Comment: Facing this error in azure pipeline:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.2.2:test (default-test) on project TestAutomation

Comment: Can you share more error information?  On the other hand , when you run the project on your local machine, will it work?

Comment: Yes it does work in spring tool suite in my local system. Thinking why it is not working in pipeline. Do you think azure-pipeline.yml is written properly or does it needs to be improved?

Comment: Please refer to the answer. You can add the steps to install the java version 11.0.19_7 to the agent and check if it can work.

Comment: It worked. Thank you for providing me the yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure DevOps Microsoft-hosted agent, the pre-install Java 11 version is 11.0.21.

But your project requests Java version 11.0.19_7. So you need to add steps to install the Java version 11.0.19_7.

Refer to the Yaml:

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest


steps:

- powershell: |
   $source = "https://builds.openlogic.com/downloadJDK/openlogic-openjdk-jre/11.0.19+7/openlogic-openjdk-jre-11.0.19+7-windows-x64.zip"
   $destination = "$(build.sourcesdirectory)\openlogic-openjdk-jre-11.0.19+7-windows-x64.zip"
   $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
   $cookie = "oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"
   $client.Headers.Add([System.Net.HttpRequestHeader]::Cookie, $cookie) 
   $client.downloadFile($source, $destination)
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'

- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use Java 11'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 11
    jdkArchitectureOption: x64
    jdkSourceOption: LocalDirectory
    jdkFile: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)\openlogic-openjdk-jre-11.0.19+7-windows-x64.zip'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: '$(agent.toolsDirectory)/jdk11'

- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/cucumber.json'
    testRunTitle: 'Cucumber Tests'
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    pathToPublish: 'test-output' # Update this with the path to your Extent Reports
    artifactName: 'extentreports'
    goals: 'verify'
```

In this case, you can keep the Java version: 11.0.19_7 in your Pom.xml file. `<java.version>11.0.19_7</java.version>`